# Записать матрицу с данными без цикла, Matlab

Tags: циклы, матрицы, matlab

Есть единичная функция задана на интервале, например:

```
t = 0 : 1000;
k = 3;
g1 = 1.*(t >= 40*(k-1) & t <40*(k));
```

Мне необходимо сделать перебор по `k`и записать в массив. Через цикл никаких проблем нет, все хорошо, например

```
for k = 1:5
    g(:,k) = 1.*(t >= 40*(k-1) & t < 40*(k));
end
```

Однако если пытаюсь сделать без цикла,

```
k = 1:5;
g1 = [];
g1(:,k) = 1.*(t >= 40*(k-1) & t < 40*(k));
```

Выдает ошибку *Matrix dimensions must agree.*
Я понимаю что значит эта ошибка, однако не понимаю или не знаю как это сделать без цикла, и можно ли в целом это сделать без цикла. С одномерным массивом проблем не возникает при уходов от циклов. Или подскажите где глянуть.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение следующим образом, может кому пригодится:

```
[t k] = meshgrid(0:300, 1:5);
kol_ot_sym = 40;
g1 = 1.*(t >= kol_ot_sym*(k-1) & t < kol_ot_sym*(k));
```

В целом решение меня устраивает, но может есть у кого-то еще варианты или замечания, буду рад увидеть. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё так:

```
t=0:500;
x = (cell2mat(arrayfun(@(z)rectpuls(t'-(2*z-1)*20,40),1:5,'UniformOutput',false)))';
```